# UML to SQL tool

Tags: sql, uml

is there some UML tool where I can draw my database design and generate SQL scripts for creating my database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can recommend Enterprise Architect from http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/

Comment: Note, the Desktop edition (the cheapest edition) of EA does NOT include "code engineering" which includes the generate DDL feature. 

See:
http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html#editions

and

http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/data_modeling/generateddlforapackage.htm

Answer (score 4):

[Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) can do that. It can also reverse-engineer existing databases.

Of course, it does a lot more than this as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Erwin from CA](http://www.ca.com/us/data-modeling.aspx) is one such tool.

We started playing with the idea of using it at a previous employeer of mine. But found the complexity of the tool and cost offset the need for it.

Answer (score 1):

argouml can do it - open source and cross-platform! but it's not yet a seamless experience, although they're working on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the online code-generation service [MOLA::UMLtoDB](http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml2db-full-code-generation-sql-scripts-databases) that automatically generates a SQL DDL script to create the database corresponding to an input UML class diagram.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what sort of SQL flavour you're using but you could try MySQL Workbench. It's cross platform and free (as in 'free speech' not as in 'free beer').

Answer (score 1):

You may try Visual Paradigm. [https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/sdevsgendb.jsp]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, several CASE (computer-aided software engineering) tools exist that will do this. Microsoft Visio is one such.

Answer (score 0):

You better use Visio, it directly creates the tables on you server n also support reverse engineering... n supports many DB systems

Comment: Visio removed this feature.  To use it, you have to use Visio for Enterprise Architects, released in 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are some:

- Micorsoft Visio
- http://www.casestudio.com/enu/
- http://www.dds-lite.com/
- http://www.ca.com/us/database-design.aspx