# relate two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

1-in mysql there is another way to relate tables without the foreign key?the relation parent-child or generalization only can be made by foreign key?

2-And for a many - many relationship (in two tables) is always need a third table?

imagine that i have 30 tables, this structure of primary key/foreign key becomes a bit confusing, no?

thanks

Comment: Re: (1), What do you mean by 'relate tables'? You can always just have some INT that your application knows refers to an ID in some other table, but are you talking about having the database enforce the relationship for you?

Comment: basically the question is: if always is needed a manual specification of each relation. can become very boring to relate many tables

Comment: @Wire Creation: If you want the DB to enforce your constraints, then yes you must specify them. How else would the DB know what to enforce?

Comment: Check this question for automated tools (UML to SQL): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733768/uml-to-sql-tool

Comment: @jwd in a generalization could possibly be avoided the "manual" foreign key. I read that can be done in phpmyadmim, so is better than nothing

Comment: thnx. Some may actually find these automated tools boring and more "fun" to create the 30 tables (or a 30-tables join) by hand. It's a matter of taste :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once you have 30 tables, foreign keys make it easier to see what is related to what.

Many-many relationship always requires a separate table.